# Access one element from array

Tags: php, arrays

Im new to php. I have following situation:

```
$params   = array("code" => $_GET["code"], "redirect_uri" => $redirectUrl);
$response = $client->getAccessToken($accessTokenUrl, "authorization_code", $params);

$accessTokenResult = $response["result"];

$client->setAccessToken($accessTokenResult["access_token"]);
$client->setAccessTokenType(OAuth2\Client::ACCESS_TOKEN_BEARER);

$response = $client->fetch("https://oauth.reddit.com/api/v1/me.json");
```

And the result (`print_r`) from `$response` is this one:

```
Array (
    [result] => Array
        (
            [name] => histograf
            [created] => 12869553489
            [gold_creddits] => 0
            [created_utc] => 12869553489
            [link_karma] => 1
            [comment_karma] => 11
            [over_18] => 1
            [is_gold] => 
            [is_mod] => 0
            [has_verified_email] => 
            [id] => ap11l
        )

    [code] => 200
    [content_type] => application/json; charset=UTF-8 )
```

The point is now, how can I access the element name? I need to have the username to step further in the pgm.

I've tried these and none work:

- `$username = $response[0];`
- `$username = $response->name;`
- `$username = $response[0]name;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
$username = $response['result']['name'];
```

- $respone = your array.
- ['result'] = The first element in your case.
- ['name'] = Access the name value.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, to get the [name] field from the response:

`$username = $response['result']['name'];`

Replace the `['name']` with whatever field it is you are trying to access. For future reference, if you are testing the output of your script in an HTML file, you can surround your `print_r()` with `<pre>` tags as such:

`<pre><?php print_r($response); ?></pre>`

This makes the `print_r()` much more readable, and you'll be able to see the depth of the array.